# Examples for Kripke semantics for intuitionistic logic

Tags: intuitionistic-logic

In my previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2046479/how-can-i-show-that-certain-inference-is-not-intuitionistically-valid/2046487#2046487),  Mees de Vries talked about Kripke semantics and
reading his links, I tried to show that $(X\wedge \neg Y)\rightarrow Z \vdash X\rightarrow (Y\vee Z)$ is valid using Kripke semantics.

Here is my answer, but I'm not sure whether it is right or not:

Since $(X\wedge \neg Y)\rightarrow Z$, for any world $u\ge w$, if $X\wedge \neg Y$ holds at $u$, then $Z$ holds at $u$.  What I want to show is for any world $u \ge w$ if $X$ holds at $u$, then  $Y\vee Z$
holds at $u$.

Let's call $u_X$ be the world where $u_X\ge u$ and $X$ holds at $u_X$. Then  For any such $u_X\ge w$, either $Y$ or $\neg Y$ holds at $u_X$.  If $\neg Y$ holds at $u_X$, then $(X\wedge \neg Y)$ holds at $u_X$. So, by the premise above, $Z$ holds at $u_X$, ans so does $Y\vee Z$. If $Y$ holds at $u_X$, then $ Y \vee Z$ holds at $u_X$.  So, it is valid intuitionistically.

Is it right?

Comment: Must be : What I want to show is for any world $u≥w$ if $X$ holds at $u$, then $Y∨Z$ holds at $u$.So, last paragraph must be : If $Y$ holds at $u_X$, then $Y∨Z$ holds at $u_X$. If $¬Y$ holds at $u_X$, then $(X∧¬Y)$ holds at $u_X$ and thus also $Z$ and $Y∨Z$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA There's some error in my question. I edited. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an incorrect step where you say, "either $Y$ or $\neg Y$ holds at $u_X$."  In Kripke semantics, you do not always have, for an arbitrary node $\alpha$ and sentence $\varphi$ that $\alpha\Vdash\varphi$ or $\alpha\Vdash\neg\varphi$.  What you do have is that either $\alpha\Vdash\varphi$ or $\alpha\nVdash\varphi$, but $\alpha\nVdash\varphi$ does not imply $\alpha\Vdash\neg\varphi$.